# How do I know when a field/row in mysql updated successfully?

Tags: php, mysql, database, performance

Right now, I have my database setup so that I insert a new row. But if the row I'm trying to insert is a duplicate (based off of my primary key `id`), then I increment the count field by 1.

Right now I want to know when I was able to create a new row instead of having it increment count. How would I do this in an efficient/proper manner?

The current method I'm thinking of doing this, is by querying the `id` first and checking if it exists. But I feel like there's a faster/better way. I've also read about triggers but I've heard that they're bad/risky to use.

Comment: Your database setup a sample please will help a lot

Comment: At the risk of stating the obvious, cant you just use php's if(mysql_query...), returnint true if it was successful insert and false if not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE...`
Then query for affected_rows (as @Tarek Fadel suggested). MySQL will return 1 if the row was inserted, or 2 if existing row were updated.

Answer (score 0):

Use your database **AUTO INCREMENT** option for your primary ID field. Only propper solution.

Here you have mysql reference, but that exist in just every database engine:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

Answer (score 0):

How about an [auto_increment](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) on the id column?

Otherwise you might use `SELECT MAX(id) FROM TABLE` to retreive the highest id and add one to it, but that isn't thread-safe since another user might execute the same insert at the same time. Auto_increment fixes that for you.

Answer (score 0):

PHP's [mysql_affected_rows()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php)